# How to show x^2 preserves convexity and it's set valued inverse does not?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am defining the set valued inverse as follows:

$$f^{-1}(C) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}|\ f(x) \in C\}$$

Then the set for the function would be:

$$f(\mathbb{R})=\{f(x) \in C|\ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

I think to show that  $f(x)=x^2$ is convexity preserving

I would need to pick $f(x_1)\in f(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(x_2) \in f(\mathbb{R})$ (which implies $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$) then show that:

$$\theta f(x_1)+(1-\theta)f(x_2) \in f(\mathbb{R}),\ \ \ \  \theta\in[0,1]$$

So then I need to show,

$$\theta x_1^2+(1-\theta)x_2^2 \in f(\mathbb{R})$$

But I am not sure how to proceed since I can't put it in the form $(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2)^2$, which I would then be able to show that since $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ which implies $(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2)^2 \in f(\mathbb{R})$.

I am aware of the definition of convex function i.e.:

$$f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y) \le \theta f(x) +(1-\theta)f(y)$$

But since we are dealing with sets instead of functions it seems to be a little different. How would $(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2)^2 \le \theta x_1^2+(1-\theta)x_2^2\ $ imply that $\theta x_1^2 + (1-\theta) x_2^2 \in f(\mathbb{R})$?

So how would I show $f(x)=x^2$ preserves convexity and it's set valued inverse does not?

Comment: What if C = R so that f: R->R?

Comment: Oops I messed up. $C = \mathbb R$ works, since $\sqrt {\theta x_1^2 + (1-\theta)x_2^2} \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Then the set valued inverse also preserves convexity since the dom(f) = R?

Comment: So here, do you mean $C$ is an arbitrary subet of  $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is univariate?

Comment: @Darklink9110 the inverse does not always preserve convexity. $\{1\}$ is convex, but $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{1,-1\}$ is nonconvex.

Comment: We have $f^{-1}(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R$, so we need to know what $C$ is.

Comment: Okay, I think I see. Yes, I was thinking that C was an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity is not preserved by the inverse image, since $\{1\}$ is convex yet $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{1,-1\}$ is nonconvex.

To show that $f$ preserves convexity, let $y_1,y_2\in f(C)$, and let $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Therefore $(\exists x_1,x_2\in C)$ such that $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$. Without loss of generality, $y_1\leq y_2$. Since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, the intermediate value theorem guarantees that
\begin{equation}
(\exists \xi\in\mathbb{R})\quad \xi^2=f(\xi)=\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2=\alpha f(x_1)+(1-\alpha)f(x_2).
\end{equation}
Now it only remains to show that $\xi$ also resides in $C$. *Hint*: since $\xi^2\in[x_1^2,x_2^2]$, either $\xi\in\left[-\sqrt{x_2^2},-\sqrt{x_1^2}\right]$ or $\xi\in\left[\sqrt{x_1^2},\sqrt{x_2^2}\right]$. Case analysis on the signs of $x_1$ and $x_2$ should yield the rest :)